# Why do I get parameter not supplied error while using stored procedure in script component?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, ssis

Problem:
Trying to create an SSIS job using SQL Server 2005 BIDS.  Job includes a Script Task and an Email Task. The script task fails at the last step and gets this error:

> Failed to open a rowset. Details: ADO Error Code: 0x Source: Microsoft
>   OLE DB Provider for SQL Server Description: Procedure or function
>   'usp_xtal_InHouse_Penetration_Summary' expects parameter '@DateStart',
>   which was not supplied.
>
> SQL State: 42000 Native Error:  Failed to open a rowset. Error in File
>   C:\DOCUME~1\TEMP~1.SUM\LOCALS~1\Temp\1\auto_Inhouse_Leads_Penetration
>   {5DA4C113-6AFC-4EB2-94E8-7D0F12E03C52}.rpt: Failed to open a rowset.

I believe the issue is due to the report being called is running off a Stored procedure and I'm not sure if the report will actually pass the params to the SP.  The reason I think this is because the error is a SQL error stating the very first param it is looking for is not being supplied.  The SP is only looking for the params being declared in this script and the script is declaring, setting, and loading the params in the exact same order as the SP.

We have other reports running running off similar SSIS jobs but none of them are using a SP.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

The following script I am providing has several msgbox()'s at various places checking to see if variables are being loaded correctly and that the script executes to that point.  It fails with the above mentioned error at the last one.

```
Public Class ScriptMain
    Public Sub Main()
        '
        Dim CrystalReportViewer1 As New CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
        Dim DiskOpts1 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.DiskFileDestinationOptions
        Dim myExportOptions1 As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions

        DiskOpts1.DiskFileName = "\\10.200.0.7\c$\Jobs\Arrivals\WeeklyInhousePenetrationReport.pdf"
        myExportOptions1.ExportFormatType = myExportOptions1.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        myExportOptions1.ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        myExportOptions1.ExportDestinationOptions = DiskOpts1

        ' Verify the path to the Crystal Report's .RPT file:
        Dim strReportPath1 As String = "\\10.200.0.7\c$\Jobs\Arrivals\auto_Inhouse_Leads_Penetration.rpt"

        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(strReportPath1) Then
            Throw (New Exception("Unable to locate report file:" & _
            vbCrLf & strReportPath1))
        End If

        ' Load the Crystal report's .RPT file:
        Dim cr1 As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

        'Dim ParamVal1 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        'Dim ParamVal2 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim ParamVal3 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim ParamVal4 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim ParamVal5 As New ParameterDiscreteValue



        cr1.Load(strReportPath1)

        'Set the logon credentials of the main report---change these values
        LogonToDatabase(cr1.Database.Tables, "SomeInstance", "SomeUserName", "SomePassword")

        'ParamVal1.Value = 2
        'ParamVal2.Value = False
        ParamVal3.Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -15, Date.Today)
        ParamVal4.Value = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -8, Date.Today)
        ParamVal5.Value = "All"

        MsgBox(ParamVal3.Value, , "Param 3")  'Good to here

        'cr1.SetParameterValue("param_SiteID", ParamVal1)
        'cr1.SetParameterValue("param_Detail", ParamVal2)
        cr1.SetParameterValue("DateStart", ParamVal3)
        cr1.SetParameterValue("DateEnd", ParamVal3)
        cr1.SetParameterValue("Agent", ParamVal3)

        MsgBox(ParamVal4.Value, , "ParamVal4")  'Good to here

        ' Set the CrystalReportViewer's appearance and set the ReportSource:
        ' This may not be needed but I kept them anyhow
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowRefreshButton = False
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowCloseButton = False
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = False

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1

        MsgBox(ParamVal5.Value, , "ParamVal5")  'Good to here


        cr1.Export(myExportOptions1)            '  Failing at this step

        MsgBox(ParamVal3.Value, , "ParamVal3")  'Never gets here
        '
        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
    End Sub

    Private Sub LogonToDatabase(ByVal ReportTables As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables, ByVal ServerName As String, ByVal UserId As String, ByVal Password As String)
        ' To Supply Logon Information to each and every Tables used in the Report
        Dim myTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table
        Dim myConnectionInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo()
        Dim myLogonInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()
        myConnectionInfo.UserID = UserId
        myConnectionInfo.Password = Password
        myConnectionInfo.ServerName = ServerName
        myLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = myConnectionInfo
        For Each myTable In ReportTables
            myTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(myLogonInfo)
        Next    

    End Sub
End Class
```